# Laravel Cron is running twice

Tags: laravel, cron, laravel-scheduler

I am using **laravel** to run my **cron**.The problem is it that all the commands are running twice.
When i add **ps -A** in my terminal it shows two enteries.

```
  964 ?        00:04:56 cron
25010 ?        00:00:00 cron
```

I have this entry in laravel :

```
* * * * * php /var/www/war-circle-web/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling#preventing-task-overlaps. If it runs every minute is very likely to be overlapping.

Comment: Is it possible that you have two users who have this cronjob?

Comment: should i run with sudo crontab or without sudo

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check for what users cron runs

> sudo ls /var/spool/cron/crontabs

you'll see few names or one - it depends

> user_name_1 user_name_2

Then you have options for:
1) update your own cron

> crontab -e

2) remove you cron

> crontab -r -u user_name

3) remove cron for another user

> sudo crontab -r -u user_name

4) update cron for specific user_name

> sudo crontab -e -u user_name